# Django aggregation--find time differences in days

Tags: python, database, django, time, aggregation

Now I can find each employee's total commissions but I want to sort them in days.

**model.py**

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True,null=True)
commission=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
ouremployee=models.ForeignKey(Employee,blank=True,null=True)
```

My sale object already recorded commission associated with each sale and each employee but now I want to find each employee's total commission with 7 days.

**views.py**

```
Sale = Sale.objects.all()
total_commission=0
TotalCommission = Sale.annotate(total_commission=Sum('ouremployee'))
```

My `views.py` doesn't work.

Here is my query:

```
Employee.objects.filter(str(datetime.datetime.now())-'sale__date') >     str(datetime.timedelta(days=30))).annotate(total_commission=Sum('sale__commission'))
```

Comment: i can not see your comment

Comment: Are you looking to find each employee's commissions for the past 7 days?